# Using zstandard to compress a file in Python

Tags: python, zstandard

So I'm using the `zstandard` python library, and I've written a helper class and function to use contexts to decompress files.

```
class ZstdReader:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def __enter__(self):
        self.f = open(self.filename, 'rb')
        dctx = zstd.ZstdDecompressor()
        reader = dctx.stream_reader(self.f)
        return io.TextIOWrapper(reader, encoding='utf-8')

    def __exit__(self, *a):
        self.f.close()
        return False

def openZstd(filename, mode='rb'):
    if 'w' in mode:
        return ZstdWriter(filename)
    return ZstdReader(filename)
```

This works really well and allows me to just use `with openZstd('filename.zst', 'rb') as f:` before using the file `f` for `json` dumping and loading.
I'm however having issues generalizing this to writing, I've tried following the documentation in the same way I did so far but something is not working. Here's what I've tried:

```
class ZstdWriter:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def __enter__(self):
        self.f = open(self.filename, 'wb')
        ctx = zstd.ZstdCompressor()
        writer = ctx.stream_writer(self.f)
        return io.TextIOWrapper(writer, encoding='utf-8')

    def __exit__(self, *a):
        self.f.close()
        return False
```

When I open a file using this class, and do a `json.dump([], f)`, the file ends up being empty for some reason. I guess one of the steps is swallowing my input, but have no idea what it could possibly be.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `zstandard`, but I would imagine that either the `ctx` or `writer` objects need to have an explicit `close()` or `flush()` operation of some sort performed on them, to make sure that any buffered data actually gets written out.

Comment: @jasonharper if I flush the wrapper, the writer and the file descriptor, then the file is non-empty and decompresses the right content but the `zstd` CLI complains about a premature end stil...

Comment: From the docs: "If `flush(FLUSH_FRAME)` is not called, emitted data doesn’t constitute a full zstd frame and consumers of this data may complain about malformed input."  Were you perhaps calling `flush()` with a different parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by jasonharper in the comments, you have to flush both the `io` wrapper and the writer itself, as follows:

```
s = json.dumps({})
iw = io.TextIOWrapper(writer, encoding="utf-8")
iw.write(s)

iw.flush()
writer.flush(zstd.FLUSH_FRAME)
f.close()
```

This results on the data being in the file, and the file being complete.